# Failed to set breakpoint (Anti-debug protection)

Tags: windows, anti-debugging, breakpoint, x64dbg

Sorry for my bad English in advance.

There is a program that has some protection. The problem is I can not set hardware and software breakpoints in x64dbg (to be more precise - not everywhere), cuz next action in program leading to crash. I use ScyllaHide plugin with almost all options enabled except special hooks.

However, there are some strange things. I can modify all code without exceptions I even don't need to stop all threads, but just to be sure that some code is not executed at patching time. So I can take necessary information by patching. It seems there is no CRC check. Also, protection does not have driver part.

Furthermore, in order to debug it i have to attach at special time (before the program is fully loaded). If I run the program under debugging or at any other time, then it crashes.

Could you give me any idea how does it detect a debugger?